# When using node js with react, do the html files go in the node js directory (server) or the react directory (client)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Having some trouble understanding where to put html files and redirect. I'm very new to react and node js and just getting started with my first project. I have authentication working well, where my App.js in my client side has some inputs and it sends that info to node js server, which authenticates.

After authentication, should I send back a response to react so react can load a new web page? Or do I simply redirect to an html file on the server side? (res.sendFile...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience. You only use nodejs actually expressjs to read database, design api and expose api endpoint to the front end. On react part, you could call the api and also setup the proxy in the package.json file. Good example to follow:https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/
You could use it as reference.